# The following problems occur when installing Heasoftpy

Tags: python

I have successfully installed and initialized `HEAsoft`, and now I try to install `Heasoftpy` in a Python environment,

I created the virtual environment using `Conda` and then installed the dependencies in that environment, and used Python setup.py build to get an error

````
2022-06-26 12:04:10 -  INFO -      setup file found ...
/home/jason/miniconda3/envs/heasoft/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/installer.py:27: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setuptools.installer is deprecated. Requirements should be satisfied by a PEP 517 installer.
 warnings.warn(
running build
running build_py
2022-06-26 12:04:12 -  INFO - ------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------
2022-06-26 12:04:12 -  INFO - Starting heasoftpy installation ...
Starting heasoftpy installation ...
2022-06-26 12:04:12 -  INFO - ------------------------------
------------------------------
2022-06-26 12:04:12 -  INFO - Creating python wrappers ...
Creating python wrappers ...
2022-06-26 12:04:12 -  INFO - Installying python wrappers. There are 747 tasks!
Installying python wrappers. There are 747 tasks!
2022-06-26 12:04:12 -  INFO - .. 1/747 install uvottfc ...
.. 1/747 install uvottfc ...
2022-06-26 12:04:12 - ERROR - Failed in generating python wrappers
Failed in generating python wrappers
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 79, in <module>
    setup(
  File "/home/jason/miniconda3/envs/heasoft/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 87, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "/home/jason/miniconda3/envs/heasoft/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
    return run_commands(dist)
  File "/home/jason/miniconda3/envs/heasoft/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 163, in run_commands
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/home/jason/miniconda3/envs/heasoft/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 967, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/home/jason/miniconda3/envs/heasoft/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1214, in run_command
    super().run_command(command)
  File "/home/jason/miniconda3/envs/heasoft/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 986, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/home/jason/miniconda3/envs/heasoft/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "/home/jason/miniconda3/envs/heasoft/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/home/jason/miniconda3/envs/heasoft/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1214, in run_command
    super().run_command(command)
  File "/home/jason/miniconda3/envs/heasoft/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 986, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "setup.py", line 19, in run
    hspinstall._do_install()
  File "/home/jason/HEAsoft-6.30/heasoftpy/install.py", line 248, in _do_install
    _create_py_wrappers()
  File "/home/jason/HEAsoft-6.30/heasoftpy/install.py", line 67, in _create_py_wrappers
    generate_py_code()
  File "/home/jason/HEAsoft-6.30/heasoftpy/heasoftpy/utils.py", line 91, in generate_py_code
    hsp = HSPTask(task_name)
  File "/home/jason/HEAsoft-6.30/heasoftpy/heasoftpy/core.py", line 49, in __init__
    pfile  = HSPTask.find_pfile(name)
  File "/home/jason/HEAsoft-6.30/heasoftpy/heasoftpy/core.py", line 525, in find_pfile
    pfiles = re.split(';|:', os.environ['PFILES'])
  File "/home/jason/miniconda3/envs/heasoft/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 675, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'PFILES'```

I would like someone to help me solve this problem,thanks
````

Comment: According to [this](https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/lheasoft/heasoftpy.html), `As of the HEASoft 6.29 release (July 2021), all downloads include and install HEASoftPy by default.` I suppose there's no need to install `HEASoftPy` separately. Try importing and using `heasoftpy ` directly in a python program.

Comment: thanks，I know what I did wrong, @Bunny